# Aquamacs and IDLWAVE

Tags: emacs, elisp, aquamacs

I've just installed the new Aquamacs 2.0 in my Mac Os X 10.6.3 and I'm 
an happy user of IDLWAVE on Aquamacs for programming in IDL. 
Unfortunately I run into a problem which I can't understand. 
I used in my configuration file to put the following 
    (setq idlwave-surround-by-blank t) 
for the beautiful space around operator. 
This used to work till 
Aquamacs 2.0 preview b3 (third beta release) 
from that on, it stops to work and every time I type an operator (the 
same for '=' '<' '>' etc) I got the following message

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable idlwave-expand-equal) 
  (lambda nil (interactive) (self-insert-command 1) idlwave-expand- equal -1 -1)() 
  call-interactively((lambda nil (interactive) (self-insert-command 1) 
idlwave-expand-equal -1 -1) nil nil)
```

Any help is welcommed

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug introduced in Emacs 23.2.  Try a newer version of the package or move to a version of Emacs based on 23.3 or 23.1.